# How to use JQuery .done()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code where at the end of function 1, function 2 is called.

```
function function1() {
    var html = "";
    html += '<div>';
    html += '<button type="button" id="button1">Click Me</button>';
    html += '</div>';

    $("#element").html(html).done(function2());
}


function function2() {
    $("#button1").prop("disabled", true);
}
```

However this does not work and the console complains that  `$(...).html(...).done is not a function`. What should I do?

Comment: What are you expecting to accomplish with that?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I was going to use function2 to disable some of the buttons created by function1. The code here is just simplified to show the problem with .done()

Comment: @SergioTulentsev please see updated post

Comment: yeah, see Darin's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) function is synchronous and you don't need any callbacks. Just call your second function after the call to .html():

```
$("#element").html(html);
function2();
```

This will ensure that `function2` will execute after updating the element with the new markup.

Comment: could you point me to the official docs where it states that .html() is synchronous?

Comment: Sure, there's already a link in my answer pointing to the official documentation of this method.

Comment: thanks but I meant the doc where it states that .html() is synchronous?

Comment: The official doc illustrates that this method takes one string parameter and returns the jQuery object. It doesn't take any callback nor it returns a promise. So you can more than safely conclude that this method is synchronous. Asynchronous methods always must have a way for the caller to subscribe to the results of the asynchronous operation. This isn't the case with the `html()` method. Also jQuery is open source project, so if you do not trust the official documentation do not hesitate to checkout the source code.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get the result you want is to structure your code as follows.

```
function function1() {
    var html = "";
    html += '<div>';
    html += '<button type="button" id="button1">Click Me</button>';
    html += '</div>';

    $("#element").html(html);
    function2();
}


function function2() {
    $("#button1").prop("disabled", true);
}

function1();
```